# Running a java file at runtime

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to grab a Java file at run time and run what is inside of the file. I want the Java file that I grab to execute and have an output. I don't know how to do this after compile. How do I run a java file at runtime? I am trying to run a .class at runtime.

Comment: Are you trying to run a .jar file or .class file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A `.java` file? You have to compile it in order to run it. A `.class` file? You just run it using the `java` command line.

Comment: I am trying to run a .class or .java or whatever will let me run the contents in the class that are saved as a .java... if i have to i can easily change the type of file it is.. that is if it is necessary to do this in order to run it

Comment: no I would compile the application and then the user inputs code and we need to compile what they wrote in at run time to check if their code is correct.. it is like a coding game/app

Comment: .class is what i am trying to run sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run the Java file you need to compile it first. Use [`javax.tools.ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29) to get the `JavaCompiler` object, then you may run it suppling the arguments like this:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int result = compiler.run(null, null, null, 
        "-d", outputDirectory, "-classpath", classPath, javaFilePath);
if(result == 0) {
    // compilation is successful
}
```

Here `outputDirectory` is desired place to put the resulting class files, and `classPath` is the classpath necessary to compile your Java file (omit it if your Java file uses standard JDK classes only). Upon successful compilation you can load the compiled class using [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and launch anything you want from it via reflection. Use custom error stream (third argument) to catch the error messages and display them in your UI.

Note that in order to use the Java compiler in Runtime your application must be launched from JDK (JRE is not enough).

Comment: thank you sooo much ill look more into this but i had that exact code and dint know why it wasnt working but it must be because of the jdk

Answer (score 0):

If the java CLASS file is in the same package then you load it using Class.forName("fully.qualified.class.path.javafile") This will give you the class file instance, you then use the "newInstance" Class method in order to get an instance of the class.

Comment: does this allow me to run the code inside the class whenever i want? and it is not in the package explorer it would be grabbed at runtime as well.. does this mean i have to create a compiler because at this point i am trying to avoid doing that

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do. If your looking to load a class file that is not part of the same package as the class thats running it then you will need to Either include the JAR that this class resides in in your class path OR load dynamically load the JAR at runtime